# Dropdown RequiredField Validation

Tags: asp.net, dropdownbox, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following `Dropdown` control

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlMonth" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px">
 <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

And a `RequiredFieldValidator` to Validate this dropdown

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlMonth" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a month" />
```

Despite Selecting the `--Select--` option, it doesnt throw the `ErrorMessage`. What is wrong?

Comment: Your code working perfectly on my side.

Comment: try to set the ValidationGroup Property

Answer (score 0):

```html
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlMonth" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px" ValidationGroup="ValidateDropDown">
     <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlMonth" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a month" ValidationGroup="ValidateDropDown" />

<asp:Button ID="btn1_Submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidateDropDown" />
```

You have to make sure that all items have the same ValidationGroup.

You can have this without the button too. But you need to make sure that the Validation group is correct.

On the page load the validator will not throw the error. It will throw the error if you had a 'month' selected and then select the initial value again. If that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code with my local version and it is working properly. The only suggestion i can give in this scenario is to specify ValidationGroup="" for validation control and button as shown below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px" ValidationGroup="month">
     <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlMonth" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a month" ValidationGroup="month" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="month" Text="submit" />
```

One might case would be the update panel. If you have placed your code in update panel then try to set update mode always and check if still causing the problem.

That's all i can say right now as you have not shared your whole code. But the above code is working properly at my local environment.